# How can I make a directory(folder) in FTP server using current date?

Tags: batch-file, ftp, command, ftp-server

Thank you for helping me in advance !

I am currently making FTP batch file to create new folders in FTP server. the problem is that I could figure out how to make folders in local but I can't not find the way to make folders naming current date  in FTP server. Could you please let me know command lines to fix this  problem?

Comment: What is your code so far that does not work? What langage/script are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with (my) [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) and its [`%TIMESTAMP%` syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp):

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "cd /remote/parent/path" ^
    "mkdir %%TIMESTAMP#yyyymmdd%%" ^
    "exit"
```